# Will a query which may take hours to execute keep executing on remote server if I close the connection after executing the command?

Tags: ssh, mysql, database-administration

If I connect to a remote database server via ssh, start mysql client and execute a query which may take a couple of hours to execute, then close the connection, will the query continue to execute until completed? Can I mysqldump in this way on a huge database, go back a few days later and expect it all to be complete?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put: no - unless you take special measures, any long lived commands on the server will terminate when the shell that `ssh` started remotely exits.  That shell will exit if you terminate your `ssh` session, or even if the TCP connection is broken (lose network connectivity, switch wifi networks, hibernate, etc).

However, there are several options to accomplish those "special measures".  From simplest to most complex/involved:

- **nohup** - simply prepend your one-line command with `nohup`.  This works if you can assume that the command will execute and then terminate itself.  Output will be sent to the `nohup.out` file in your current directory.   Example:

  ```
  nohup sh -c "sleep 5; echo done" &
  ```
- [**screen**](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) - `screen` will setup a virtual terminal window that will not exit when your `ssh` connection terminates.  You can reconnect to the server at a later time and see the status of any commands you were running and issue new commands.  Example:

  ```
  % client: ssh server
  # server: screen
  # server[0]: mysql -e 'really long query'
  <disconnect>
  ```

  The later come back and:

  ```
  % client: ssh server
  # server: screen -RD  # -RD says "reconnect to my previous screen, even it already attached"
  # server[0]: <right where you left off in the previous screen>
  ```

  There are lots of options to `screen`, you can create several "terminals" inside of one `screen` session, and you can configure it extensively in the file `~/.screenrc`.
- [**mosh**](https://mosh.mit.edu/) - a replacement for `ssh` which will maintain the session regardless of network connectivity.  As you migrate between wifi networks, or even hibernate/awaken your machine, `mosh` will reconnect to the server.  Additionally, it will provide a lag free interface to work through, so as you type your commands, you not be affected by link or server slowness.  Note that mosh uses `ssh` to establish the initial connection and setup the UDP server on the remote end.

Comment: Screen is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Closing the SSH connection will end any processes started within that session.

Take a look at the `screen` command, wich let's you start a session within a shell then reconnect to it later from another local or remote shell.