# SSH Keep Commands Running

Tags: mac, ssh, compile

If I SSH into another machine from my macbook, start compiling a very large project, and then power off my macbook, will the compiling continue on the remote machine despite having lost connection to my macbook?

Comment: You could run it in the background using `nohup`, to prevent it from being killed if you logout.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you're using a tool like [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)... but that's one of the reasons such tools exist.

Comment: Screen is really the way to go for your requirement, as you can "disconnect" from the screen session and the task will continue along as if you hadn't.  Best of all, you can reconnect to that same screen session later and see the results of your compilation output.  Just type `man screen` in Terminal and you can get an overview of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered many times, including [here](https://superuser.com/questions/812288/will-a-query-which-may-take-hours-to-execute-keep-executing-on-remote-server-if/812677#812677).
Summary, use one of `nohup`, `screen`, or `mosh`.