# Execute Script Via SSH And Disconnect Immediately

Tags: ssh, sh, nohup

The idea is to connect to a remote machine via ssh and execute a shell script without waiting for it to finish.

EDIT: The issue was ssh, not nohup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a query which may take hours to execute keep executing on remote server if I close the connection after executing the command?](https://superuser.com/questions/812288/will-a-query-which-may-take-hours-to-execute-keep-executing-on-remote-server-if)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

> ssh myhost 'nohup /home/me/myscript > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &'

Notice the redirections and in-direction.  In my case, myscript takes no input and I don't care about the output so I'm using /dev/null for everything.  You can adjust these values as you see fit.  The `< /dev/null` is used to avoid waiting on input.

I wish I could take credit, but I saw this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine

Visit that link for more details about exactly what's happening.